# Multiple inputs in one validation rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

```
return [
'contract_code' => 'required', 
'name' => 'required|string',
'abbreviation' => 'required|string',
'linecount_divisor' => 'required|integer'
];
```

```
// into input fields => 'required'
```

How to shorten the validation rule in multiple inputs?

Comment: May I know the reason behind idea of shortening validation rule?

Comment: To shorten the code, I have multiple inputs with the same validation rule which is 'required'.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to write like this only, Currently There is no other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You have the same validation rule for multiple and you want to shorten your code just use form requests.

```
php artisan make:request RequestName
```

And then in the controller Functions use it

```
public function save(RequestName $requestName)
{
}
```

don't forget to use that request class.

```
use App\Http\Requests\RequestName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution assuming all input fields need to have a common rule like required.

```
$rules = array_map(function($curr) { return [$curr => 'required']; }, array_keys(request()->all()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one in Laravel

```
$validation=array();
        $validation= [
            'contract_code' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|string',
        'abbreviation' => 'required|string',
         'linecount_divisor' => 'required|integer'
        ];
       
        $this->validate($request,$validation);
```